# The number of ways to place distinct balls in identical bins

Tags: combinatorics

> Count the number of ways to place 6 distinct balls in 4 identical bins.

I tried to use “Stirling number” for this problem.
\begin{align}
S(n,k) &= S(n-1,k-1) + kS(n-1,k)  \qquad\text{if}\ 1 < k < n \\
S(n-1,k-1)  &= \binom{n+k-1}{k-1} = \binom{9}{3} = \frac{9!}{3!\cdot 6!} = 84 \\
kS(n-1,k) 4 \binom{n-1}{k} &=  \binom{5}{4} = \frac{5!}{4!} = 5  = 20
\end{align}
$$84 + 20 = 104$$

However, the correct answer is $342$.

Comment: Is each bin to receive at least one ball ?

Comment: This is a recursive formula.  Yes, $S(6,4)=S(5,3)+4S(5,4)$ but then you have to use the same formula to compute $S(5,3)$ and $S(5,4)$ until you get down to the initial conditions.

Comment: Okay thanks! What would the  "initial conditions" be in this case?

Comment: Can you answer my question ? If some bins can remain empty, I find a result equal to 317 not 342.

Comment: Last question : is "identical" the same as "not discernable" one from the other ?

Comment: S(6.4)=65 and not 342. See for example:https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=q9XACwAAQBAJ&pg=PA117&lpg=PA117&dq=stirling+number+s(6.4)&source=bl&ots=JMlqO6r3kM&sig=ACfU3U3Ms0OH71UGHz1BRECMPeRjCbG_fA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjuuoGv75biAhUGJBoKHSK4DWE4ChDoATADegQICBAB#v=onepage&q=stirling%20number%20s(6.4)&f=false or http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheSecondKind.html

Comment: The stated answer does not make sense.  There are only $S(6, 4) + S(6,3) + S(6, 2) + S(6, 1) = 187$ ways to place six distinct balls in $4$ identical bins, including those cases in which one or more of the bins is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The stated answer is too large.  We can partition the number $6$ into at most four parts in the following ways:

\begin{align*}
6 & = 6\\
  & = 5 + 1\\
  & = 4 + 2\\
  & = 4 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 3 + 3\\
  & = 3 + 2 + 1\\
  & = 3 + 1 + 1 + 1\\
  & = 2 + 2 + 2\\
  & = 2 + 2 + 1 + 1
\end{align*}

These partitions correspond to the following distributions.

$6$:  All six balls can be placed in one bin in one way.

$5 + 1$:  Five balls can be placed in one bin and one ball can be placed in a different bin in six ways, depending on which ball is placed in a separate bin.

$4 + 2$:  Four balls can be placed in one bin and two bins can be placed in a different bin in $\binom{6}{4} = 15$ ways, depending on which four balls are placed together.

$4 + 1 + 1$:  Four balls can be placed in one bin and the other two balls can be placed in separate bins in $\binom{6}{4} = 15$ ways, again depending on which four balls are placed together.

$3 + 3$:  Suppose the balls are six different colors, including blue.  There are $\binom{5}{2} = 10$ ways to choose which two balls are placed in the same bin as the blue ball.  The other three balls must be placed in another bin.

$3 + 2 + 1$:  There are $\binom{6}{3}\binom{3}{2}\binom{1}{1} = 60$ ways to distribute the balls to three bins so that one bin receives three balls, another bin receives two balls, and the third bin receives one.

$3 + 1 + 1 + 1$:  There are $\binom{6}{3} = 20$ ways to distribute the balls to four bins so that one bin receives three balls and each of the other bins receives one ball, depending on which three balls are placed together.

$2 + 2 + 2$:  Suppose the balls are different colors.  If we list the balls in alphabetical order, there are five ways to choose which ball is placed in the same bin as the first ball on the list.  That leaves four balls.  There are three ways to pick the color of the ball that is placed in the same bin as the first ball remaining on the list.  The third bin must hold the remaining two balls.  Hence, there are $\binom{5}{1}\binom{3}{1} = 15$ ways to distribute the balls so that two balls each are placed in three of the indistinguishable bins.

$2 + 2 + 1 + 1$:  There are $\binom{6}{2}$ ways to choose which two balls will be placed in a bin by themselves.  That leaves four balls to distribute to the remaining two bins in such a way that each such bin receives two balls.  If we list the remaining balls alphabetically, the color of the ball that is placed in the same bin as the ball with the first color on that list can be chosen in three ways.  Hence, there are $\binom{6}{2}\binom{3}{1} = 45$ ways to distribute the balls so that two bins each receive two balls and two other bins each receive one ball.

That gives a total of $1 + 6 + 15 + 15 + 10 + 60 + 20 + 45 = 187$ ways to distribute six distinct balls to four indistinguishable bins.

In terms of Stirling numbers of the second kind, the above calculations show 
\begin{align*}
S(6, 1) & = 1\\
S(6, 2) & = 6 + 15 + 10 = 31\\
S(6, 3) & = 15 + 60 + 15 = 90\\
S(6, 4) & = 20 + 45 = 65
\end{align*}
Note that $S(6, 1)$ corresponds to the $6$ balls in one bin case; $S(6, 2)$ corresponds to the distributions $5 + 1$, $4 + 2$, and $3 + 3$; $S(6, 3)$ corresponds to the distributions $4 + 1 + 1$, $3 + 2 + 1$, $2 + 2 + 2$; $S(6, 4)$ corresponds to the distributions $3 + 1 + 1 + 1$, $2 + 2 + 1 + 1$.
In total, there are 
$$S(6, 1) + S(6, 2) + S(6, 3) + S(6, 4) = 1 + 31 + 90 + 65 = 187$$
ways to distribute six distinct balls to four indistinguishable bins.

Comment: Very comprehensive answer indeed. I think that the sum of $s(n,k)$ is used when empty boxes are allowed but OP did not mention this. In fact the OP was asked but did not answer (yet)!

Comment: I had done a similar analysis. I agree with you almost entirely but for the $2+2+1+1$ count that should be IMHO $\binom{6}{4}\binom{4}{2}=15 \times 6=90$. Remark : at first, you do not mention the case  2+2+2, but you treat it.

Comment: @JeanMarie  Thanks for alerting me to the omission of the $2 + 2 + 2$ case from my list of partitions.  In the $2 + 2 + 1 + 1$ case, I assume you selected which two of the six balls would be placed in the same box and which two of the four remaining balls would be placed in a different box.  However, the boxes are indistinguishable, so we must divide $\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}$ by $2$, which yields $\frac{1}{2}\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2} = 45$ such distributions.

Comment: @NoChance  You are correct that $S(n, k)$ is the number of ways of placing $n$ distinct in $k$ indistinguishable boxes when no box is left empty.  The reason I included those cases in which one or more boxes is left empty is that the question does not specify that each box must contain a ball.

Comment: Thank you for explaining me where was my error.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks i will accept this :) But what formula do you use to get s(6,2) = 6 + 15 + 10 = 32 ?

Comment: @DanielAndersson $S(n, k)$ is the number of ways of placing $n$ balls in $k$ indistinguishable bins when no bin is left empty.  If we use only two bins for six balls, there are three possibilities:  five balls are placed in one bin and one in the other ($5 + 1$), four balls are placed in one bin and two in the other ($4 + 2$), or $3$ balls are placed in each bin ($3 + 3$).  I obtained the result $S(6, 2) = 6 + 15 + 10 = 31$ by adding the numbers obtained for those three distributions.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using Stirling numbers: here is another method based on [Burnside's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside%27s_lemma).

There are $4! = 24$ symmetries (permutations) of the $4$ boxes.  Of these:

- $1$ of them (the identity) has $4$ fixed points and therefore leaves all $4^6$ possible ball placements unchanged.
- $N$ of them has $1$ fixed point and therefore leaves a ball placement unchanged iff all the balls are in that fixed box.  The number of such ball placements is $1^6 = 1$.  The number of permutations with $1$ fixed point is $N = 4\times 2 = 8$, because there are $4$ ways to pick the fixed point, and then $2$ ways to rotate the remaining $3$ points s.t. there are no more fixed points.
- $M$ of them has $2$ fixed points and therefore leaves any ball placement unchanged iff all the balls are in those $2$ fixed boxes.  The number of such ball placements is $2^6$.  The number of permutations with $2$ fixed points is $M = {4 \choose 2} = 6$ because you choose the fixed pair and the remaining pair must swap.
- It is impossible to have a permutation with $3$ fixed points.
- There are of course permutations with $0$ fixed points (in fact, $24 - 1 - 8 - 6 = 9$ of them) but these leave no ball placements unchanged, so they contribute zero in the Burnside formula.

So by the (almost magical) Burnside's Lemma, the number of placements is:

$${1\over 24} (1 \cdot 4^6 + 8 \cdot 1^6 + 6 \cdot 2^6 + 9 \cdot 0) = 187$$