# What ist the number of arrangements to place $N$ distinct balls equally into two distinct bins?

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to find a closed formula for the number of arrangements $\Omega_N$ to distribute $N$ distinct balls $\textit{equally}$ into two distinct bins, labelled with $L$ and $R$, i.e. $L$ contains $N/2$ balls and $R$ contains $N/2$ balls. I was able to derive a formula, but I am not sure if it is correct. It would be great if you could help me checking it.

I quickly guide you through my reasoning and then give the formula.

Note that we assume that $N$ is always an even number.

Starting with two balls, $N=2$. I label them with 1 and 2 and easily find $\Omega_N=2$, since we have the arrangments: $L:1$ and $R:2$, and for symmetry reasons $L:2$ and $R:1$.

For $N=4$, I find $\Omega_N=6$, again by counting. We have arrangements: $L:12$ and $R:34$, $L:13$ and $R:24$, $L:14$ and $R:23$. For symmetry reasons we can change $L\rightarrow R$, and I find two times three, i.e. six.

To find a closed formula for $\Omega_N$, I tried to count the number of possibilities when I fix again the first ball, labelled with 1, in the bin $L$. With the help of the answer to this question [1], the number of possibilities to place the remaining $N/2-1$ other balls in $L$ should be $\binom{N-1}{N/2-1}$. Thus, I find:
$$\Omega_N=2\binom{N-1}{N/2-1}$$

with the factor two for symmetry. This gives the correct result for $N=2,4$. For $N=6$ this gives $\Omega_6=20$. However, by brute force counting I only find ten different arrangements and I am confused. Either I cannot count or my formula is not correct.

Is the formula for $\Omega_N$ correct or am I missing something?

Thanks a lot for your help!

[1] [The number of ways to place distinct balls in identical bins](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3223256/the-number-of-ways-to-place-distinct-balls-in-identical-bins?newreg=df114abcaa6841f1bac22b1932dbbb18)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is correct. It is also equal to $2\binom{N-1}{N/2-1} = \binom{N}{N/2}$, where you directly choose the $N/2$ items to go in the left bin, the remaining ones in the right.
Although there are only 10 ways to split 6 items into two groups of 3, there are 20 ways if you then put them in distinct bins.